# How to fix that when variable is compared it becomes undefined in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, undefined, nan

I'm creating a small game as a test for my JavaScript skills. For some reason I cannot figure out, when I compare the variable `iron` and the variable `drill`, `drill` becomes undefined, and listed as `NaN` in my webpage.

I'm using Javascript and HTML on repl.it. I feel it may be an issue with my `If` statements, but I'm not sure how to fix them if that is the source of the issue. Also, the variables `iron` and `drill` are set to `0` default.

```
  if (iron < drillPrice) {
    alert("Not enough iron");
  }
  if (iron >= drillPrice) {
    drill = drill + 1;
    tempDrills = drill
    iron = iron - drillPrice;
    document.getElementById('drillsOwned').innerHTML = drill;
    iron = Math.round(iron * 10) / 10;
    document.getElementById('ironOwned').innerHTML = iron;
    drillPrice = Math.floor(100 * Math.pow(1.1, drill));
    document.getElementById("drillPrice").innerHTML = drillPrice;
  }
}
```

The full repl is here: https://repl.it/@Munix/factory

The output expected if the variable `iron` is higher then the variable `drillPrice`, it should make `drill` one higher, in this case making `drill` equal `1`. What actually happens is `drill` becomes `undefined`. If the variable `iron` is lower than `drillPrice`, it should display the test `Not enough iron`, and not touch the variable `drill`. What actually happens is it displays the test `Not enough iron`, but sets `drill` to `undefined`.

Comment: The comparison operators absolutely do not alter the values of operands.

Comment: @Pointy This is why I am fairly sure it is an issue with my ```if``` statements. I likely have not worded the title very well.

Comment: Have you set drill to zero (initialized your variable)? It may help to post your entire code or the repl link so we can see everything

Comment: @TanyaGupta At the start, it is set to 0. The repl link is here: https://repl.it/@Munix/factory

Comment: Some moden JS patterns: don't use `alert`, use `console.log` (or real page code for presenting information to your users). Also, unless you're _actually_ setting HTML content (which should be almost never, because if you know what the HTML is, you can use DOM functions instead), don't use `innerHTML = ...`, use `textContent = ...`

Comment: You are overwriting the value of `drill` somewhere in the random events loop, by using the `drill = tempDrills` at the wrong time. Haven't found the exact position yet. Great example of why overusing global variables leads to annoying to find bugs, since basically any part of your program can overwrite those values. So Look for a better structure if you intend to make the game even more complex.

Comment: In your randomEvent function you're setting drill = tempDrills,  tempDrills is undefined at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is this part of the code:

```
function randomEvent() {
  var event = Math.random();
  event = Math.round(event * 10);
  if (event <= 9) {
    document.getElementById("event").innerHTML = "No event today!";
    drill = tempDrills
  }
  if (event == 10) {
    var eventFlavor = 'You have iron deficiency! 1/2 iron from drills for the rest of the day!';
    document.getElementById("event").innerHTML = eventFlavor;
    var tempDrills = drill;
    drill = drill / 2;
  }
}
```

What we see here, is an example of how variables are created in javascript:
`var tempDrills = drill;`
The declaration of the variable is hoisted to the top of the function, so it basically looks like this:

```
function randomEvent() {
  var event = Math.random();
  var tempDrills;
  ...
}
```

So the variable gets hoisted and will not be set to the value of `drill`, unless you are lucky enough to roll the 1 in 10 on startup. So `tempDrills` is a local variable with the value undefined in the other 9 cases, explaining the behaviour once you set `drill` back to `tempDrills`.

The solution is silmply to remove the `var` keyword, so you use the global variable instead. Then it works as expected for me.

Answer (score 0):

## I have figured out my own question, thanks to @Shilly's comment.

I had a `drill = tempDrills` at the incorrect time, causing it the variable `drill` to become `undefined`. By removing this, I managed to get the code to work.